# What is the chemical name of this derivative of aniline?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the chemical name of the following compound?

$$\ce{(C6H5)-N=CH2}$$

I doubt that it might be N-phenyl methanal oxime . But  , it can't be oxime of OH ion is absent.  What would it be?

Comment: It is N-phenylmethanimine being an imine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred name is *N*-phenylmethanimine, but often it is named *N*-methyleneaniline (or *N*-methylenaniline, more correct one would be *N*-methylideneaniline though).

**UPDATE** a typo (excessive "e" in bogus "phenylmethaneimine") fixed. (thanks, Loong)

Comment: +1 If you want, you can include this link in your answer (https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/N-Methyleneaniline#section=Top). Your call though :-)

Comment: @paracetamol I don't :) already seen it, but kinda intentionally did not mention it, since the bunch of various names (sometimes bad) is not prioritised (i did little literature search what name is often used); it's a helpful comment anyway